# How to declare TypeScript import * type?

Tags: types, casting, typescript, type-conversion, strong-typing

How can I explicitly declare type at import * as ... in TypeScript?

I'm having this code:

```
import * as UnauthorizedInterface from './interfaces/InterfaceA'
import * as AuthorizedInterface from './interfaces/InterfaceB'

export class App extends React.Component<{children?: React.ReactChildren, authorized?: Boolean}, {}> {
public render() {
    return <Router>
        <Route component={Interface}>
            <Route path="/application" components={InterfaceA}
...
```

and I'm getting

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App.tsx
(16,24): error TS2322: Type 'typeof "~/src/interfaces/InterfaceA"'' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>; }'.
Index signature is missing in type 'typeof "~/src/interfaces/InterfaceA"'.
```

though it's only exporting entities extending React.ComponentClass

Answer (score 0):

> import * as UnauthorizedInterface from './interfaces/InterfaceA'

I think you probably mean to do `import {UnauthorizedInterface} from './interfaces/InterfaceA'`. Of course if you use the *module* (which is what you get with `* as`) as a class you would get the error which is what you are getting.

Comment: No, I definitely meant "* as" - I wanted to use simple syntax to declare list of components which in sum would be an interface.
in JS that would be a common object.

Comment: @Jabher did you find what is the typing of the import?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. Basically wanted to

```
import * as Util from './Util'
```

And then use Util as an argument. This works by using `typeof Util`

```
function thing(localUtil: typeof Util) {...}

thing(Util);
```